# jQuery PageBeforeShow Event Binding Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having code like following

```
  $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#Newpage", function (event) {
    $(".newtext").change( function() {
            dostuff();
        });

    });
```

Now the problem is every time the NewPage is loaded , the binding of

> $(".newtext").change( function()

occurs and it is triggered multiple times.So for 1st time if I open the page dostuff() happens once, if I navigate to some other page and come back to #Newpage again it occurs twice and so on

Comment: `$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#Newpage"` if you pasted in some global function try to put that in `pageinit` function of jqm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).one("pagebeforeshow", "#Newpage", function (event)
```

Comment: your solution works, however it means that if i click a button in that page and navigate back (by using the jquery back button) to that page, the pagebeforeshow doesnt fire, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

set isFirstTime value true at very first, best place is deviceready event

`window.sessionStorage.setItem("isFirstTime", true);`

pagebeforeshow event occurs every time page before loads need to maintain in session storage or localstorage or local variable like that only

`$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#Newpage", function (event) {
    $(".newtext").change( function() {
            if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("isFirstTime");){
                dostuff();
            }
        });
    });`

In your function

`function dostuff(){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("isFirstTime", false);
    // do your code below...
}`

I hope this example helps you problem.